# Could the Stack automatically post a ping-back comment on referenced Questions?

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be useful for questions to have links to any meta-discussions about them. This is inspired by The Oracle, which posts new meta questions to Chat.

**Could the site automatically post a comment like "This item has been referenced in [this meta question]" to any questions or answers so referenced?**

Additional options around user experience include a default-on check box for posting this message, and including the original question title on the link.

An alternative proposed by @nitsua60 is to allow Linked questions to work between main and meta, rather than just within their own sites. This creates an automatic, bidirectional connection between two questions by creating links in the Linked section of the sidebar.

Another alternative, inspired by my own misinterpretation of nitsua's idea, is to have another section to the sidebar specifically for out of site references. For both this idea and his, I think I prefer my original suggestion because it gives the ability to refer to specific answers as well as specific questions. I am open to changing my mind on this.

Comment: Even just having the auto-detection magic that goes on in the "linked" sidebar work across the meta-main boundary woudl be awesome.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's what ignorance gets me. Thanks for the information. Updated.

Comment: How these things work under the hood is totally not obvious! If it must be called "ignorance", it is only in the gentlest, most technical meaning. :)

Comment: Just to be clear: I'm not suggesting a new portion of the sidebar. Currently the sidebar creates a "Linked" heading and populates it any time a post  (or comment) includes a link to another question, [like this unrelated one](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7200/23970). See! It's over there right now! (And the target automatically gets a back-link to the originating post.) But this-all only works with meta Qs on meta, or mainsite Qs on mainsite. If this behavior worked across the meta/main boundary, we'd already have what you're asking for.

Comment: @nitsua60 Apologies for rushing that edit. If I'm still misrepresenting you, or you'd like to clarify anything, feel free to edit.

Comment: @JoelHarmon that looks good, and makes sense to me. No worries =)